# NGRX effect using firestore stateChanges method completes due to auth error after logout

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, ngrx

I am building a small Angular chat app with AngularFire2. 
Once the user logs out, all of my NGRX effects that are using AngularFire´s `.stateChanges()` & `.valueChanges()` methodes complete due to an auth error. How is it possible to keep the effects "alive" after logout?

I´ve already tried something like using the RXJS operator `takeUntil` with some kind of auth Observable that reflects if the user is logged in. Same thing for `takeWhile`. I´ve alos tried `catchError` as last operator and inside an extra `pipe()` after the `firestoreService.getUserFriends` method.

The NGRX Effect:

```
@Effect()
query$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Query>(SocialActionTypes.Query),
    withLatestFrom(this.store$),
    map(([action, storeState]) => {
      return storeState.auth.user.uid;
    }),
    exhaustMap(uid => this.firestoreService.getUserFriends(uid)),
    mergeMap(actions => actions),
    map(action => {
      return {
        type: `[Social] Friend ${action.type}`,
        payload: {
          ...action.payload.doc.data(),
          id: action.payload.doc.id
        }
      };
    })
);
```

The firestoreService.getUserFriends method:

```
getUserFriends(uid: string) {
  return this.afStore
    .collection<Friend>(`social/${uid}/friends`)
    .stateChanges();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add catchError directly to getUserFriends() method?

Comment: `.getUserFriends(uid)
        .pipe(catchError(e => from(null)))` results in the effect beeing completed silently. Changing `from(null)` to `of(null)` results in an error that an observable stream was expected.